# Opacity filter makes text less white, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm making a movie-page where I want to make the photos in the moviecards darker while hovering on it but when I add opacity, the text (that I want to be white) also gets darker. How can I make the photo background to be darker without making the text dark?

This is my code:

(CSS)

```
h1 {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
 }

 p {
   display: none;
 }

 h2 {
  color: #fff;
 }

 p.movieOverview {
   color: #fff;
   display: flex;
   max-width: 400px;
 }

 .movieCard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 3px;
}

 .movieCard:hover {
  background: 0, 0, 0, .75;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
 }

 .movieCard:hover p {
  display: unset;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: unset;
  font-size: 1vw; /*vw gör font-size responsiv*/
  position: absolute;
  /*started with top:-10 to get the text in right square, apparently I didnt need it*/
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}

 .movieCard:hover h1 {
  display: unset;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: unset;
  font-size: 3vw; /*vw gör font-size responsiv*/
  position: absolute;
  /*started with top:-10 to get the text in right square, apparently I didnt need it*/
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

(react javascript)

````
<div className="movieList">
      {movie.map((movie) => (
        <Link key={movie.id} to={`/movies/${movie.id}`}>
        <div className="movieCard">
        <img className="cardImage" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${movie.poster_path}`} alt=""/>
        <div textContainer>
            <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
            <p className="releaseDate">Released {movie.release_date}</p>
          </div> 
       </div>   
        </Link>
      ))}
      </div>  
    </section>
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the rendered HTML, not the react script. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That said, you have the `opacity` changing on the `.movieCard` element. That affects ALL children elements. I would highly recommend using a pseudo element on the `movieCard` that changes darkness on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `opacity` property affects the children elements of the targeted element too so what you can do is just apply the opacity directly to the image inside your movie card instead like this:

```
.movieCard:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```css
#someDiv:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="someDiv">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="someImg">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```